# Quebra linhas na criação do .pdf com SynPDF

Tags: delphi-10

Minha duvida é a seguinte. Tenho uma `String` com mais de 6000 Caracteres e preciso por o conteúdo dessa variável em um arquivo **.pdf**. só que salvo para o pdf o texto fica em uma unica linha, ele não quebra a `string` para por em outras linhas.

Vou por aqui o código de como salvo a `string` em **.pdf**.

```
...
uses
  SynPdf;

{$R *.dfm}
...
procedure TForm2.SalvarPdfClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  PDF : TPdfDocumentGDI;
  Page: TPdfPage;
  FileName: string;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  ...
  Descricao := JsonValue.Value;

  PDF  := TPdfDocumentGDI.Create();
  try
    PDF.Info.Author       := 'Autor';
    PDF.Info.CreationDate := Now;
    PDF.Info.Creator      := 'Criador';
    PDF.Info.Subject      := 'Assunto';
    PDF.Info.Title        := 'Título'

    Page := PDF.AddPage;
    Page.PageLandscape    := False;
    PDF.DefaultPaperSize  := psA4;
    PDF.VCLCanvas.TextOut(100,100, Descricao);
    PDF.SaveToFile('C:\MySysten\Pdf\Pdf_Publ.pdf');
  finally
    PDF.Free;
  end;
```

O texto fica assim e não quebra para as próximas linhas [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizado ***Synopse PDF engine*** para salvar em **.pdf**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa!
Passei por isso tem um tempinho e acabou que eu resolvi fazer de outro modo mais com o ***Synopse PDF engine***. Veja ai se te ajuda.

No `Uses` coloca assim:

```
uses
...
SynCommons, SynPdf, mORMotReport,
...;
```

E no código você pode por mais ou meno assim:

```
with TGDIPages.Create(self) do
try
  Caption := 'Título Aqui!';
  BeginDoc;
  SaveLayout;
  Font.Size := 9;
  AddTextToHeaderAt(Caption,LeftMargin);
  TextAlign := taRight;
  AddTextToHeader(DateTimeToStr(Now));
  AddLineToHeader(true);
  TextAlign := taLeft;
  AddLineToFooter(true);
  AddPagesToFooterAt('Page %d/%d',LeftMargin);
  TextAlign := taRight;
  AddTextToFooterAt('Testo de Rodapé',RightMarginPos);
  RestoreSavedLayout;
  DrawTitle('Título do capítulo',true);
  AppendRichEdit(RichEdit.Handle);
  DrawTitle('Last page content',true);
  NewHalfLine;
  DrawText('Seu Texto...');
  EndDoc;
  ExportPDF(FileName,True,False);
  ShowPreviewForm;
finally
  Free;
end;
```

Esse Exemplo eu retirei direto do Site: [synopse.info/forum](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=76) i visual do **.pdf** fica muito bom e bem organizado no [site](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=76) vai tem um link para download do fonte de exemplo.

Comment: Vou dar uma olhada sim. Só pode ser com `RichEdit` tem uma com  `Memo`?

Comment: Tente adaptar...